# FunctionalInterface with two non-default methods

Tags: java-8, functional-interface

I was looking at `Comparator<T>` interface from `java.util` and I saw the fact that is annotated with `@FunctionalInterface`.

Can someone please explain me why a compile error is not present since two non default methods are present in the interface?
The methods are:

```
int compare(T o1, T o2);
```

and

```
boolean equals(Object obj);
```

Comment: Interface methods matching `public` methods declared in `java.lang.Object` do not count. This applies to `boolean equals(Object)`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. There is some documentation somewhere saying this? I'm quit surprised because is the first time when I hear this.

Comment: Refer : [java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html) paragraph 1

Comment: The formal specification is set in [JLS §9.8. Functional Interfaces](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.8)

Comment: Now I was thinking more about it... It makes sense since every functional interface is an object and already contains those methods :)

Comment: And the methods of a non-interface class like `java.lang.Object` always take precedence, so if you declare a `default boolean equals(Object obj) { … }` rather than an `abstract` method, the implementation class will still use the method inherited from `java.lang.Object`…

Comment: In this case what is the purpose of the equals method in Comparator interface?

Comment: To add a javadoc comment whose contents appears in the documentation of the `interface Comparator`.

Comment: Great answer Holger! Thank you!